# Azure Functions v2 - New .netcore Configuration and deployment

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-functions

Now that we can use the hugely flexible configuration engine from .NETCore - we can do something like this :

```
   private static IConfigurationRoot SetConfig(ExecutionContext executionContext)
    {
        return new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(executionContext.FunctionAppDirectory)
           .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables()
           .Build();
    }
```

Which is great as it allow you to put more complicated configuration data in the config file - for instance

```
    {
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<< removed >>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "<< removed >>"
  },
  "MyCustomSettings": [
    {
      "ConnectionString": "<< removed >>",
      "Folders": [
        {
          "ShareName": "share1",
          "FolderName": "folder1"
        },
        {
          "ShareName": "share2",
          "FolderName": "folder2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Again - great news! I can now get access to my strongly typed configuration with config["MyCustomSettings"]

What I don't get though - is how this can be deployed when publishing the function. Only the Values section is migrated to the Azure function Application Settings. I can obviously put this custom json in a json file and add it to the load statement like the local.settings.json

```
.AddJsonFile("my-custom-settings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
```

but then this file has to be included in the deploy, and is not stored securely.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is not officially supported as of Nov 2019.

> **[Warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#working-with-options-and-settings)**
>
> Avoid attempting to read values from files like local.settings.json or appsettings.{environment}.json on the Consumption plan. Values read from these files **related to trigger connections** aren't available as the app scales because the hosting infrastructure has no access to the configuration information.

<strike>There are so many blogs around advising to do this and it appears this may work if you only have a single instance, but as soon as the ScaleController triggers scaling, new instances will not be able to find the config files.</strike>

If you have triggers that use the `%SettingName%` syntax, they will not work as the function scales.

Functions team [is](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3189) [considering](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4761) [possible](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4517#issuecomment-498457562) [*Options*](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4464#issuecomment-511590422) (lol)

There is also the option of using the new **[App Configuration](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-configuration/)** service but it is currently in preview and isn't available in all Azure regions.

<strike>It may be simpler to put your config in blob storage, and load it at startup? (Your blob store connectionstring will need to be in env variables)</strike>

So far the *best* we can do is to include your "not so secret" settings (things like `MyThingTimeout` or `ExternalEndpointAddress`) in a json file and use `.AddJsonFile(...)` and put secrets in KeyVault. This does force you to split your config and decide which goes where. (And also make sure your triggers only read from the Values section/Environment Variables)